# How to retrieve the member from a file that is declared as transient in Java Deserialization concept?

Tags: java, deserialization, transient

In Java Deserialization, transient keyword used to restrict the data from the user. If we want to retrieve these data, then we have the default value of that variable as follows:

Student.java

```
public class Student implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

int id;
String name;
static String college;
transient int age;
public Student(int id,String name,int age) {
    this.id=id;
    this.name=name;
    college="SVS";
    this.age=age;

}

}
```

and Deserialization.java

```
public class Deserialization {
public static void main(String ar[]) throws Exception {

    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("SerializeOutput.txt"));

    Student s = (Student) in.readObject();
    Student s1 = (Student) in.readObject();

    System.out.println(s.id + " " + s.name+" "+s.age);
    System.out.println(s1.id + " " + s1.name+" "+s1.age);

    in.close();
}

}
```

Here, I have the original values of `id` and `name`, but I am getting the value for `age` as 0(I know for int).

I want to retrieve the original value of `age`.

Is it possible to retrieve the desired value?

Comment: In case field is marked as `transient`, java will not write it to output stream when object is serialized. Since you don't have it in stream, you cannot retrieve value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Members marked as `transient` won't be serialized, hence `age` is not part of the persistent state of the object.

When you de-serialize, since there is no data preserved for the `age` field it gets Java's default value for `int` (0).

Answer (score 0):

No. If a field is marked as `transient`, then it is not serialized *at all*, it is completely missing from the class's serialized format. So the data is not there for you to retrieve.